# Python ftplib uploads failing with error 421

Tags: python, ftplib

I'm currently trying to upload a file to a ftp server using Python's ftplib library.  The file is relatively small (~400MB), but my script always crashes the same way:

```
total_size = 492917709
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ftpmule.py", line 83, in <module>
    dest_ftp.storbinary('RETR %s' % base_fn, fhandle, 1024)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ftplib.py", line 233, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ftplib.py", line 266, in getresp
    raise error_temp, resp
ftplib.error_temp:  421 Data timeout. Reconnect. Sorry.
```

Relevant code:

```
dest_ftp = FTP(ftp_dest_host)
dest_ftp.login(ftp_user, ftp_pass)
dest_ftp.cwd(ftp_dest_path)

filename = "file.zip"

with open(filename, 'rb') as fhandle:
    dest_ftp.storbinary('RETR %s' % filename, fhandle, 1024)
```

Comment: Have you tried to transfer the file with a good old command line ftp (outside of Python) and does it work or fail the same?

Comment: Yes -- the upload works fine and is pretty fast (10.59 seconds @ 45390.6 kB/s).  One thing I did notice is when the transfer was initiated I got "200 PORT command successful.  Consider using PASV".  I'm pretty sure ftplib using PASV by default though.

Comment: And did you try to force the passive mode in command line ftp?

Comment: So if I try 'mode PASV' I get "we only support stream mode, sorry.".  I'm assuming I need to make sure I connect in active mode through my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you comments, the server does not support the passive mode. Python ftplib uses passive mode by default since 2.2, so you have to explicitely disable it with `set_pasv(False)`:

```
dest_ftp = FTP(ftp_dest_host)
dest_ftp.login(ftp_user, ftp_pass)
dest_ftp.cwd(ftp_dest_path)
dest_ftp.set_pasv(False)

filename = "file.zip"

with open(filename, 'rb') as fhandle:
    dest_ftp.storbinary('RETR %s' % filename, fhandle, 1024)
```